# writing over a disconnected socket does not throw

Tags: java, sockets, exception, tcp, disconnect

the writer:

```
   socket.setSendBufferSize(1);
   socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
   writer = new BufferedWriter(
          new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

is used as follows:

```
try {
        writer.write(packet.toXML());
        writer.flush();
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception ioe){
        if (!done) {
            done = true;
            ... 
        }       
    }
```

This is client side code. When its server disconnects the socket (also java code), how come the client will only throw after 5 - 10 minutes ? Should it not throw at the first attempt to write over the dead connection ?

Thanks

Edit:

after shutting down the server, here are the TCP states:

```
tcp        0      0 server:443     client:50283   FIN_WAIT2 

tcp4       0      0  cient.50283     server.443       CLOSE_WAIT
```

Edit2:

client is an android application. Ran from phone, the second packet written causes a throw. Ran from an emulator (Mac underneath) the fourth write() will throw.

Comment: Can you do a netstat in the command prompt and see what is the state of your TCP connection? Maybe the server wasn't able to close the connection properly yet?

Comment: Is the server explicitly closing the socket, programmatically? Or are you just cutting off its network access or something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should it not throw at the first attempt to write over the dead
>   connection ?

No. All it knows is that a FIN has been received, which could have just been a shutdownOutput() by the peer - it could still be reading. So TCP has to send the data. If the peer has closed, it will issue an RST, which TCP will provide to the application on a *subsequent* write.

Comment: ok, i understand this state is reached when only one side (server here) sends the FIN,ACK while the other side (cient here) does not send the same back to server. Can I somehow tweak the java client so that the TCP layer would immediately send FIN,ACK back to its server ?

Comment: @kellogs The FIN ACK is sent when you close the socket or shut it down for output. The real point is that if you are writing to a socket that has been closed by the other end, you shouldn't be: it's an application protocol error.

Comment: right, and I would relly like to fix that :). So i am on the client side, in java. Is there any kind of notification that java would fire upon a FIN,ACK from server ? it probably aids that the socket is being reaad through the XMPP pull parser library :-s

Comment: @kellogs A read() would return -1, readLine() returns null, readXXX() throws EOFException for any other XXX. In TCP there is no way to detect a lost connection except via I/O.

Answer (score 0):

According to docs, readers should return -1 on read() operations, but I was not getting anything because some XmlPullparser was getting in the way

```
parser.setInput(connection.reader);
```

So, the writer behaves as EJP described above, but if you have access to source code then we could instantiate our connection.reader as some InputStreamReaderEx like so:

/**
 * @author kellogs
 *
 */
public class InputStreamReaderEx extends InputStreamReader {

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.io.BufferedReader#read()
 */
@Override
public int read() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int ret = super.read();

    if (ret == -1)
    {
        int l = 4;
    }

    return ret;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.io.BufferedReader#read(char[], int, int)
 */
@Override
public int read(char[] buffer, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int ret = super.read(buffer, offset, length);

    if (ret == -1)
    {
        int l = 4;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

}

and get notified when the other peer goes away